# How can I tell if SP1 has been installed on VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, installation

How can I tell if SP1 has been installed on VS2008? e.g. If I'm working on a co-worker's machine - how can I tell if he/she has installed SP1 for VS2008?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In Help->About, you can view the installed products. You should see something similar to

> Microsoft Visual Studio Team System
>   2008 Team Suite - ENU Service Pack 1
>   (KB945140)   KB945140

in the list of entries.

Answer (score 15):

Open Visual Studio 2008 and click Help>About. If you do have MS VS SP1 installed, the upper left corner should look like this:

Microsoft Visual Studio 2008
version 9.0.30729.1 SP

The upper right corner states what version of Microsoft .NET Framework you have and may show that it has SP 1 installed, but this DOES NOT mean you have Visual Studio SP 1 installed.

Here is a link to a picture: http://quick-page.net/46ad2310

Hope this helps!
Iconoclast

Answer (score 2):

You may also be able to tell by looking in the registry here

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\DevDiv[ProductFamily]\Servicing\9.0\

then finding a property named something like "SP" or "SPIndex". A value of 1 means installed, and 0 means not installed.

[Tip was found here](http://younsi.blogspot.com/2008/12/how-to-detect-if-visual-studio-2008-sp1.html).

Answer (score 0):

It also puts a little '9' in a white box on the program icon. (Probably not dependable, of course)

Comment: That indicates that it's VS2008, but it may or may not be SP1

Comment: This may be because I installed RTM over Beta 2, but I only got the 9 in SP1