# How can I tell if I have Visual Studio 2008 SP1 installed?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I installed a new machine and am using an iso file that was provided to me by my employer (en_visual_studio_team_system_2008_team_suite_x86_dvd_X14-26461.iso).  I was wondering how I know whether I need to install the latest service pack for visual studio, or whether it is already installed from the .iso file.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tell if SP1 has been installed on VS2008?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160948/how-can-i-tell-if-sp1-has-been-installed-on-vs2008)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In visual studio, help about shows the visual studio version.  If there's an sp1 next to the version, then you have it installed.  It also shows the 3.5 .net framework version, whether or not you have that sp1 installed.

Comment: Specifically, the Visual Studio 2008 SP1 version will show "Version 9.0.30729.1 SP" on the left side of the About dialog.

Comment: It's ridiculous & confusing, why not put SP1 instead of just SP? beats me.

Comment: After Installing SP1, mine VS2008 says "Version 9.0.30729.4462 QFE" in help>About.
I've downloaded ISO and installed it from ISO.

Comment: What I ment to say is that the version was like that after installing from ISO.

Answer (score 3):

Help > About Visual Studio

Answer (score 2):

It should simply be listed under the details when you launch Visual Studio and navigate to

> Help > About Microsoft Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

Open Visual Studio.
Click on menu : Help > About
Check the version there